# How to set a specific queryset on a ObjectSerializerModel

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a web system using Django 1.11 and the current version of Django Rest Framework which is 3.8.2.

I'm having a problem while serving a JSON of my models in this project. I need to pass a JSON that contains a specific attribute.

I'm gonna exemplify my serializers.py to make an easier understanding of my problem.

```
class LikertSerializerModel(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = Likert
        fields = ('id', 'escala')

class RespostaSerializerModel(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likerts = LikertSerializerModel(many = True, read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Resposta
        fields = ('id', 'resposta','tipo', 'foto', 'pergunta', 'qtd_escolhida', 'classificacao_escala', 'data', 'likerts')

class PerguntaSerializerModel(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    respostas = RespostaSerializerModel(read_only=True ,many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Pergunta
        fields = ('id', 'pergunta', 'tipo_questao', 'questionario', 'respondida', 'data_inicial', 'data_final',
                  'obrigatoria', 'outros', 'ordem', 'qtd_max_caracteres', 'respostas')

class QuestionarioSerializerModel(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entrevistadores = UsuarioSerializer(many = True, read_only = True)
    sub_administrador = UsuarioSerializer(read_only= True)
    perguntas = PerguntaSerializerModel(many = True, read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Questionario
        fields = ('id', 'titulo', 'descricao', 'data', 'duracao', 'localizacao', 'sub_administrador', 'entrevistadores', 'perguntas')
```

**THE PROBLEM:** See, in the PerguntaSerializerModel I have this field "respostas". And the thing is, I only want to pass to that Pergunta Object, Resposta Objects that have a "tipo" attribute with a value of "alt" and are linked with that Pergunta Object.

**PS:** If you need an explanation of how those classes are linked, here it goes (we can ignore the Likert Object as it is useless to the problem):

A **Resposta Object** is linked by a ForeignKey to a single **Pergunta Object**, and a **Pergunta Object** is linked by a ForeignKey to a single **Questionario Object**.

A **Questionario Object** can have one or more  **Pergunta Objects** and a **Pergunta Object** can have one or more **Resposta Objects**

When you do a GET in the rest URL the final JSON will start with the Questionario Object, and will cascade until the last Pergunta Object.

Please help me to find an answer, I wasn't able to find one in the REST documentation because I don't know what I need to look for.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is a [SerializerMethodField()](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). You can read through the docs for more info on it.

Create a method on the serializer `PerguntaSerializerModel` that returns a filtered queryset of `Resposta` objects on the basis of attribute `tipo`.

Something like this should work fine:

```
class PerguntaSerializerModel(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    respostas = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Pergunta
        fields = ('id', 'pergunta', 'tipo_questao', 'questionario', 'respondida', 'data_inicial', 'data_final',
                  'obrigatoria', 'outros', 'ordem', 'qtd_max_caracteres', 'respostas')

    def get_respostas(self, obj):
           reposta_qs = obj.filter(reposta__tipo='alt')
           resposta_serailizer = RespostaSerializerModel(reposta_qs, read_only=True ,many=True)
           return resposta_serailizer.data
```

Let me know if this helps !